Ubuntu 24.04 tigervnc: Authentication is required to create a color profile
I am using ubuntu 24.04 and tigervnc. When I resize the window for example to fullscreen I must Authentication is required to create a color profile.
I found different solutions and all say I should create a file in /etc/polkit-1/localauthority.conf.d/.
I have tried:
[Disable Color Management Authentication]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.color-manager.create-device
ResultActive=no

Also I tried:
[Allow Colord all Users]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.color-manager.create-device;org.freedesktop.color-manager.create-profile;org.freedesktop.color-manager.delete-device;org.freedesktop.color-manager.delete-profile;org.freedesktop.color-manager.modify-device;org.freedesktop.color-manager.modify-profile
ResultAny=no
ResultInactive=no
ResultActive=yes

Nothing is working. Because tigervnc not working in ubuntu 24.04 as normal I start tigervncserver with following command: export GDK_BACKEND=x11 && export CLUTTER_BACKEND=x11 && tigervncserver -xstartup /usr/bin/gnome-session
Maybe this cause the problem? I am not sure why but I must start a new gnome-session in tigervnc. Is my polkit policy not working for new gnomw-sessions?
